# Full stop is also indexed in Tridion CM search

Tags: web8, content-manager, search, search-engine

Our editors tried searching some content in Tridion CM search and sometimes they did not get any results for a particular word. Upon investigation we found that the last word was indexed along with fullstop (.)

For eg, consider the below sentence:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

So if we tried searching '***elit***', there were no results. However if we try '***elit.***', we were able to get the results.

Is fullstop (.) also indexed along with last word? Is this default behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried this on 2013 SP1 and the behavior is indeed the same.

Running Solr Analyzer shows that a full stop remains after processing:
http://localhost:8983/#/tridion/analysis?analysis.fieldvalue=elit.&analysis.query=elit.&analysis.fieldname=CatchAll

The problem is that "text" field type in Solr schema does not have a filter which removes delimiter characters (usually solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory or lately solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory).

You should be able to fix this by adding delimiter filter to "text" field type in the schema (%TRIDION_HOME%\Tridion\solr-home\tridion\conf\schema.xml), but it's quite possible that it was left out for a reason (for example, to be able to search for a namespace in a template).

There's also a workaround - to use asterisks in the search field:
 *elit* should return the expected results.

Comment: The workaround looks to be a better option at the moment. Thanks :)